# How To Print A Phone List From My Contacts List Using OWA?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2003, outlook-web-access

In Outlook 2003 or 2007, if you:

1. Open your Contacts folder.
2. From the **File** menu, select **Print**.
3. The Print dialog box will open.
4. Beneath **Print style**, select **Phone Directory Style**.

This will print all your contacts as a phone directory. Can the same be done from OWA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just go to file > print, however OWA (tested on 2007) has no built in way of easily printing (and formatting) contacts.